# How to use XAML binding with the following {Binding Model.Errors[ClassName.PropertyName]}

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Binding in xaml spits out the following error:

```
System.FormatException: Indexer did not contain closing bracket
```

How can I provide the class and property name as a string value inside the Model.Errors[string value with dot(s) here]

This works

```
Text="{Binding User.Errors[Forename]}"
```

This does not when trying to add the string value with a dot

```
<Label Text="{Binding User.Errors[UserDetail.PhoneNumber]}" />
```

Having the dot allows me to have the scope of the inner class and property name on the c# side. I could replace the dot with a + but then I'm assuming I would have to build some converter to change the + to a dot when it reaches the c# side?

Not sure if there is some other kind of format or way to achieve this, without writing out the additional converter logic?

Comment: This is my first question I've asked on SO and I didn't want to add a link in the post as I'm not sure if it's considered bad etiquette due to links going bad, so I thought I'd include it inside this comment.

I'm following David Britch's tutorial on adding validation in Xamarin Forms, which will hopefully give you some additional background into what I'm trying to achieve.

[Validating User Input in Xamarin.Forms](https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/03/validating-user-input-in-xamarinforms-iv.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use the source, Luke:](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindingExpression.cs) Xamarin's XAML parser apparently does not allow such syntax: it doesn't parse the path properly, but just splits the whole path string by `.`. To work around this limitation, I suggest a minimal value converter that lets you keep the `.` for member access:

```
// error handling and boilerplate omitted
public class ErrorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((ErrorCollection) value)[(string)parameter] ;
    }
}
```

Then use it in bindings like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding User.Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter},
     ConverterParameter='UserDetail.PhoneNumber'}" />
```